# Explanation for javascript code used in the plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, elementor

I have a javascript like this. Can someone tell what `.scope.find` doing the code and from where `carousel_elem.data('settings');` is getting the array? I could only see a JSON `data-setting="{"arrow:true,...` in the HTML

```
var WidgetLAECarouselHandler = function ($scope, $) {    
  var carousel_elem = $scope.find('.lae-carousel, .lae-posts-carousel, .lae-gallery-carousel, .lae-services-carousel').eq(0);
  if (carousel_elem.length > 0) {    
    var settings = carousel_elem.data('settings');    
    var arrows = settings['arrows'];
    var dots = settings['dots'];
    var autoplay = settings['autoplay'];
```

Comment: The `data-setting="{"arrow:true,...` is a data attribute called "settings", and its value is a JSON string. When fetching the attribute value (using `.data("settings")`), it's automatically converted to an object. The code then uses bracket notation to access the properties of this `settings` object, e.g. `settings['arrow'];` will refer to `{"arrow": true}`.

Comment: `$scope` is presumably a jQuery object passed in to the function, so `find()` will be searching for descendant elements matching the selector: https://api.jquery.com/find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope` could be a node passed to the function, and `find` search in your descendant elements the selector.

`carousel_elem` is the the array returned by the function that has property as `data-setting`, which you can retrieve through `data` function. e.g:

```
var settings = carousel_elem.data('settings');
```

HTML could look like this:

```
<div class="lae-carousel" data-settings="{'arrows': true, 'dots': 'foo', 'autoplay': true }"><div>
```

Comment: is there any way to see that in console?

Comment: also if you can tell me what eq(0) stands for? Thank you :)

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla eq, is the index of returned elements into array, the `eq(0)` will get the first element, further information here https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/